# Unsure of how to implement this transition/animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

So I was able to create a 'flip-card' element; however, my issue is that I am trying to scale the entire element using transform: scale() so that about halfway through the rotation, I want the element to begin expanding to a bigger size/scale.

Just not sure if I use animations, multiple animations, or transitions only...or transitions + animation...just a bit confused what is the most effective approach.

I tried animations + transitions, like shown below, and it's very glitchy and acting unpredictably.

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 2s;
} 

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

.flipcard:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  animation: grow 1s; 
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='flipcard'>
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would the desired behavior be in terms of after the animation is finished? Card stays flipped when hovered over and immediately goes back to its original state when unhovered? Card flips when hovered over and animates in reverse when unhovered? Card flips and grows, then once it's finished with the animation, resets even if you're still hovering?

Comment: Thank you for asking; I should've clarified. Essentially, I would hover over the card, it would flip, and begin scaling to a larger size. While still hovered, the card will remain at the maximum scaled sized specified, and on the back (ideally) of the card will be writing. As long as I am hovered over the card, I do not want the animation to reset/reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is that you are using transform in different places: in the hover state and in the animation. So one is **overriding** the other which create your issue. rotate and scale should be combined in the same transform property and you should start with `scale(1)` not `scale(0)`. Then you should add `forwards` to the animation so you keep the last state when the animation ends.

---

In your initial code when you hover, the rotation is ignored as the transform of the animation will override the transform in the hover state. Then you will scale your element to 0 which means your element will have 0 height and width and you **will lose the hover** and your element will suddenly appear again (since there is no more hover so no more animation) and so on. This is the flicker you are having.

You may tell me why sometimes it works? Simply because if you have some luck (if the cursor is close to the middle) the animation will continue before you lose the hover and then it will end. When the animation ends, no more scale and the transform with rotation will now be considered.

---

Another important thing to consider when rotating an element on the Y axis : if the rotation is `90deg` then your element will have a width equal to 0 at this state and you may also lose the hover again. An idea to avoid this is to add the hover to a container and rotate the child so that you will be sure you will never lose the hover as the container won't move.

```css
html,
body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
.flipcard {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

.container:hover .flipcard {
  animation: grow 1s forwards;
}

.front-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='flipcard'>
    <div class='front-side'>
      <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='back-side'>
      <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer 1000 times; it was well-explained and written out, and covered problems that I didn't even know how to begin asking. Thank you; I just learned a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use both `scale` and `rotate` transforms in a single animation.

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 2s;
} 

@keyframes growandflip {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
  }
}

.flipcard:hover {
  animation: growandflip 2s; 
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='flipcard'>
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, so this is pretty close to what I want, however, I'm not sure if you noticed, but when you start a hover on the element, it flashes on and off repeatedly, in a very glitchy manner. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I was about to answer the same and Temani has already explained it.

Comment: Not at all; I appreciate the help regardless. :)

Answer (score -1):

```css
@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. And maybe a working example.

Comment: sorry for the late, here is an example https://codepen.io/kaiten/pen/jZRrMe?editors=1100