# how do animation without keyframes but with transition

Tags: javascript, css, animation

```css
div {
    height: 41.4vmin;
    width: 30vmin;
    margin: 0.7vmin;
    border-radius: 1.3vmin;
    background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/60933/tkZK7aYQUjM.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
}


@keyframes example {
  0% {}
  35% {background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/60933/tkZK7aYQUjM.jpg");}
  36% {background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/6092c/fR8eCsT009k.jpg");}
  100% {background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/6092c/fR8eCsT009k.jpg");transform: rotateY(160deg);}
}

div:hover {
  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I don't use keyframes because i need set unique url for every animation. If i do this then need creator more 100 keyframes. 
And i want to do this because with transition can set different url method js. But this not look how i want.

```css
div {
    height: 41.4vmin;
    width: 30vmin;
    margin: 0.7vmin;
    border-radius: 1.3vmin;
    background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/60933/tkZK7aYQUjM.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    transition: 
    /* step 1 */
    transform      1s,
    /* step 2 */
    background  0.0s 0.5s;
}



div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(160deg);
  background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/6092c/fR8eCsT009k.jpg");
}
```

```html
  <div></div>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and it makes if more of a hassle for us to have to go to another site to see your code. Just include your code in a "code snippet" right here in your question.

Comment: transition only can hold timing of one change for real animation you need the animation keyword.

Comment: Okey 
thank you for editing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, you can create two elements `front` and `back` that lies inside `card-container` element and animate accordingly:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.card-container').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.card-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 41.4vmin;
  width: 30vmin;
  margin: 0.7vmin;
}

.card-container > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 1.3vmin;
  transition: transform 1s, background  0.0s 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card-container .front {
    background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/60933/tkZK7aYQUjM.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-container .back {
  background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/6092c/fR8eCsT009k.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-container.clicked .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-container.clicked .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>

<div class="card-container">
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help
I didn't tell that i need start animation on click. if i will use your code then i can't listen event `click` due to `after`.

Comment: @Pegos I modified my answer.

Comment: I saw your solution, everything work perfect. But only with one card, which i try set the class `click` into more than one, animation doesn't work.
I'll be very grateful, if you advise true solution
of course thank for that answer.

Comment: Well, I added another -card-container with the same content and my code works properly. Can you elaborate more what's going wrong?

Comment: I need set class click on more that one -card-container. Don't one card, and two or more

Comment: You want to add `clicked` to every card? You can replace `$(this).toggleClass('clicked');` with `$('.card-container').toggleClass('clicked');`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the transition to the hover state and adjust the delay and you will have exactly the same thing:

```css
div.card {
  height: 41.4vmin;
  width: 30vmin;
  margin: 0.7vmin;
  border-radius: 1.3vmin;
  background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/60933/tkZK7aYQUjM.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

div.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(160deg);
  background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/6092c/fR8eCsT009k.jpg");
  transition:   transform 1s linear, background 0s 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 100 URL's to do this? You only need the front of the card image and the back of the card image.

```css
img {
      width:100%;
      border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
      border-radius:1vw;
    }

    .container {
      /* Position and Size the Container */
      position: absolute;
      top: 17%;
      bottom:0; /* Needed to keep the overall height larger than the card. */
      left: 20%;
      width: 25%;
 
      /* Will inherit to children only (not all descendants) */
      perspective: 900px; 
    }

    #card .front {
      /* Flip the front side of the card by rotating it around the y-axis. */
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    #card:hover {
      /* Rotate the card as a whole:  */
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    #card div {
      /* Forces both elements to come out of the normal flow and occupy the same space on the page. */
      position: absolute;

      /*
        The backface-visibility CSS property determines whether or not the back
        face of the element is visible when facing the user. The back face of 
        an element is always a transparent background, letting, when visible, 
        a mirror image of the front face be displayed. If your foreground element
        is opaque, this property may not need to be set.
      */
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    #card {
      /*
        Indicates that the children of the element should be positioned in the 3D-space.
        And, pass any inherited perspective along to children.
      */
      transform-style: preserve-3d;

      /* 
        Changes to the transform property should take 1 second to
        change from their current value to their new value. 
      */
      transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.75,1.25,.5,1.25);
    }
```

```html
<!-- The "container" will be the 3D space for us to work in.   -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- The "card" is the single entity that we will manipulate. -->
    <div id="card">   

      <!-- The child elements make up pieces of the overall object.--> 
      <div class="front"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Ace_of_spades.svg/2000px-Ace_of_spades.svg.png"></div>
      <div class="back"><img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3172829/620603528/stock-vector-ace-of-spades-with-eyel-vintage-design-t-shirts-620603528.jpg"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: This is great. I might recommend moving the `:hover` event up to a parent element so the rotation on `#card` doesn't jank up while moving your cursor around the card during the transition.

Comment: you should pay attention to the flicker, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078460/unsure-of-how-to-implement-this-transition-animation/49078862#49078862

Comment: @JonUleis If the hover is moved to `.container`, the effect no longer works.

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is not applicable here. What you are seeing here is simply that as the card rotates, depending on where your mouse is, it may wind up no longer being over the card and so hover no longer applies and the effect reverts. Your linked answer describes something else entirely.

Comment: yes i know is a complete different thing ;) but am talking about the rotation ... better apply hover on a fixed heigh/width element and rotate the child to avoidt the state when you are at 90deg and the mouse lose hover .. which is a part i explained in this answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Additionally, your effect (in your link) acts the same way, but your flip goes faster than mine so it's a little harder to make it happen in yours that's all.

Comment: @TemaniAfif As I mentioned, moving the hover to the `.container` breaks the effect entirely.

Comment: i never said moving it to container :) i simply said that we need to pay attention to flicker effect and shared a link where i show how we can fix it ... your code is fine, i simply added a comment about this

Comment: @ScottMarcus I suggested moving the `:hover` to a parent element, but not the transform/transition. It wouldn't break the effect - you would just need to rewrite the rule to be `.container:hover #card { }`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a [`transition-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) with palindromic timing, so the card image changeover can always be in the middle. Examples of this include `linear` or `ease-in-out` (incorporated below).

Note that some browsers don't support `transition` on `background-image` though, so you may need to approach this effect differently for it to work in IE, for example.

```css
div {
  height: 41.4vmin;
  width: 30vmin;
  margin: 0.7vmin;
  border-radius: 1.3vmin;
  background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/60933/tkZK7aYQUjM.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, background 0s .5s;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotateY(160deg);
  background-image: url("https://sun9-8.userapi.com/c840530/v840530203/6092c/fR8eCsT009k.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```